# Android Nougat Media Player how put music Animation in Lock Screen?

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, android-notifications, android-music-player

I am using the original Music player in android Nougat, while the music is playing in the Lock Screen Appear an animation in the Buttom like this screenshot.

[image]

But when i using my own App Media Player in the same Android Nougat and Same device in the Lock Screen dont appear that animation.

[image]

The question is: How can i Add that animation in my Media Player App? it´s not a gif image because The animation moves to the rhythm of the music.

**This is my Notification Method ** if i am missing something or if i have to add something else.

```
ublic void Custom_Notificacion(){

    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.logobubble, null, System.currentTimeMillis());

    notificationView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.layout_notificacion_personalizada);

    notificationView.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.id_FotoAlbumNotif,FotoNotif);
    notificationView.setTextViewText(R.id.id_NombreMp3Notif,NommbreArtista);
    notificationView.setTextViewText(R.id.id_NombreCancionNotif,NombreCancion);

    notification.contentView = notificationView;
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;

   startForeground(constantes.NOTIFICATION_ID.FOREGROUND_SERVICE,notification);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've read an article about this,an feasible solution is  custom a lock screen page and display the Animation view within it,to achieve this you need a Service   listening to the **LOCK_SCREEN Broadcast**,and start your **LockScreenActivity** ;replace the system lock screen at the same time.
here is some code segment might be helpful:
**Register Broadcast Receiver**

```
IntentFilter mScreenOffFilter = new IntentFilter();
mScreenOffFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
registerReceiver(mScreenOffReceiver, mScreenOffFilter);
```

// on receive method

```
 private BroadcastReceiver mScreenOffReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals(NOTIFY_SCREEN_OFF)) {
        Intent mLockIntent = new Intent(context, LockScreenActivity.class);
        mLockIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
        startActivity(mLockIntent);
    }
}
```

**Disable the Lock screen**

```
KeyguardManager mKeyguardManager = (KeyguardManager)getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
KeyguardManager.KeyguardLock mKeyguardLock =  mKeyguardManager.newKeyguardLock("CustomLockScreen");
mKeyguardLock.disableKeyguard();
```

Hope this could be a little help

Comment: I will try this, thanks for your anwser, if this works i will return.